# Rest Assured code not allowing to use println

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to automate twitter API. when tried to print "js.get("text") using

> System.out.println(js.get("text")); I am getting error as 
>   "The method println(boolean) is ambiguous for the type PrintStream"

I downloaded jars and passed in Build path as well "scribejava-apis-2.5.3" and "scribejava-core-4.2.0"

Below code is not allowing me use println for ------>js.get("text")

---

public class Basicfunc {

```
String Consumerkeys= "**************";
String Consumersecretkeys="*******************";
String Token="*******************";
String Tokensecret="***************************";


@Test
public void getLatestTweet(){

    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses";
    Response res = given().auth().oauth(Consumerkeys, Consumersecretkeys, Token, Tokensecret).
    queryParam("count","1").
    when().get("/home_timeline.json").then().extract().response();


    String response = res.asString();
    System.out.println(response);
    JsonPath js = new JsonPath(response);
    System.out.println(js.get("text")); 
}
```

}

Comment: Is that actually your actual API key? You may want to remove that STAT, although it's potentially comprimised by now.

Comment: Reset those keys

Comment: I already proposed an edit to remove them

Comment: @jonathanHeindl good

Comment: now someone just needs to review them ...

Comment: I regenerated the keys and still it shows the same error

Comment: @MadhusudhanR The suggestion to reset the keys was because sharing the keys allows other people to use your API account. The problem you posted is a separate issue. Never share secret keys like that online.

Comment: theyre even called secret :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.out.println(js.getString("text"));` instead of `System.out.println(js.get("text"));`, because `get` [returns any primitive value](https://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/1.4/com/jayway/restassured/path/json/JsonPath.html#JsonPath(java.lang.String)).

I think your problem is that your [twitter response is actually a list](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-home_timeline.html).

Try to use `System.out.println(js.getList()[0].get("text"));` and be aware that you are only using the first `[0]` entry and ignoring the rest.

Comment: for same code above I am getting error as "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/scribejava/core/model/AbstractRequest"
can anyone help me with this now?